About my first project . in need of guidance
so this is my sophomore year in college . And for some time i wanted to make a project from the scratch . and i not know how to get started in making my first project in ai/ml .

I don't know if this might be exactly the right place for your question, but to answer your question, you need to know why exactly you want to do a research project. Is it to learn how to do research in machine learning/AI? Is is to learn a programming language? Is it to try to get published in a journal or a conference? These three goals can require different work to do.

If you are trying to learn how to do research in machine learning/AI, you could start off by trying simple projects. First, you need a dataset. There are many datasets available online: for example, you can find many on Kaggle. From this dataset, you would then need to go through the entire machine learning research process. There are many, many resources online for this; over a period of time, this would be a great learning experience so that you would be much more acquainted with research in ML. You could also look for research that other people have done before, and try to replicate their results yourself. Starting off with complex models such as neural networks would not be best; you could start of simple with linear/logistic regression, or decision trees, for example.
If you are trying to learn a programming language, such as R or Python, as you are in college, you could take classes on it, for example. Then, with that knowledge of the programming language, you could apply it to machine learning research.
If your goal is to get published (assuming you already know a programming language that is "good" for machine learning), it would still be advisable to follow the first bullet point and go through the research process in replicating research that other people have already done. Then, you would need to think of a research idea, and apply the research process that you learned to it. Then, you could try to submit your work to a conference or a journal. It would be best, through this process, if you had an actual mentor: as you are in college, you could try to find a professor who could mentor you through the research process and eventually lead to publication.

